# WooCommerce Hook: Content get's displayed twice and not AFTER the order total

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks, actions

I've overwritten WooCommerce's `review-order.php` to change the checkout a little bit. Now everytime I add something to the hook `woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total` the contents get displayed twice and before the whole block and NOT AFTER the order total:

```
function output_payment_button() {
    $order_button_text = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_button_text', __( 'Place order', 'woocommerce' ) );
echo '<input type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '" data-value="' . esc_attr( $order_button_text ) . '" />';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total', 'output_payment_button' );
```

Also adding a simple `<?php echo("Hello World"); ?>` to the end of `review-order.php` makes it appear twice. Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try `return` instead of `echo`

Comment: @Pim - doesn't work with return unfortunately

Answer (score 5):

In case it helps anyone, the do_action('woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total') is called in the middle of a table in the template and expects a table row to be echoed by the add_action hook. If you just echo text or, as in the question, an input, it falls outside the table, appears before not after the table and presumably gets left behind on ajax updates so appears more than once. So, something like the following will work in the add_action hook (the table has 2 columns):

```
echo '<tr><td colspan="2">My after totals text</td></tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably if you check again the file `review-order.php` you will see that you replace the hook `woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total` with `woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total`, which probably now is present two times.

If you see twice what you attached to the hook, is just because the hook is used twice.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Antonio. I'm not sure I understand your point, as I'm using `woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total` only once. Also `woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total` exists and has not been replaced. I commented out every other `do_action()` hook except `woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total` and still it appears two times. Could you be please so kind and elaborate on your answer?

Comment: It appears only once when I remove the classes from the surrounding `<table class="shop_table woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table">` element in `review-order.php` which is very strange.

Comment: Did you also try to comment out also that specific hook and check if it still happens one time? Also, did you search in the whole theme folder if that hook is used somewhere else?

Comment: Yes I did that, it's used only once within the whole theme - it only appears once when removing the `class` content from the table element (HTML) - so maybe it's related to AJAX.